# Auto Sizing static, multi-line UILabel in a static UITableView Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

OK.  I'm looking to do something that I hope is rather simple and I can chalk up the last few hours of Googling / searching as a learning experience.  I have a UISplitViewController (iOS 7+, iPad) with UITableViewControllers as the Master and Detail View Controllers.  All of this works fine; the Detail View Controllers load correctly on selection.

I'd like to display a static UITableViewController with n sections and a single row in each section. In each row I'd like to have a single UILabel that displays multiple lines of static text and I'd like the UITableViewCell / row to be correctly-sized based on the orientation of the device, namely 10 points of padding on top and bottom using AutoLayout.

This should be simple, but the answer eludes me.  If you're trying to picture this in your head, imagine that I want to have 5 Help sections separated visually or 12 sections of a EULA, both of which are in my requirements...

Here's what I've tried:  I tried to subclass UITableViewCell to somehow know its height.  This didn't seem feasible because the height is set in UITableViewDelegate.  Then I subclassed UITableViewController and attempted to create a "virtual" UILabel and size it via the heightForRowAtIndexPath override:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width-20, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = dataTextLabel.font
        label.text = dataTextLabel.text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height+28
}
```

But, this is bad.  To make things "seem" right I had to put in some fudge factors.  Through experimentation I found that subtracting 20 points from the frame width and adding 28 points to the sized UILabel's height gave me the best possible approximation.  However, this is far from good.  When there's more text, the spacing is obviously off.  Also, as a stand-in I did this to only include a single block of text that I attach here:

```
@IBOutlet var dataTextLabel: UILabel!
```

There has to be a better way and I have to believe that this comes up all of the time.  I've seem many examples on the Interwebs, but they seem to always be with dynamic tables and they have all of the text in their code.  Some of my text, namely some legaleze will be very lengthy and I'd rather not have this carried around as Strings.

So, how can I have static text in a static UITableView and have the text be correctly sized based on orientation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there are still defects in Apple's self-sizing table view cells:  http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html